# Elasticsearch: unexpected relevancy score for optional fields in documents

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I'm probably missing something trivial here, but I'm having issues with the relevancy score of the search results when it comes to optional fields in documents. Consider the following example:

**Test data:**

```
DELETE /my-index

PUT /my-index

POST /my-index/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"required_field":"RareWord"}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"required_field":"RareWord"}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"required_field":"CommonWord"}
{"index":{"_id":"4"}}
{"required_field":"CommonWord"}
{"index":{"_id":"5"}}
{"required_field":"CommonWord"}
{"index":{"_id":"6"}}
{"required_field":"CommonWord"}
{"index":{"_id":"7"}}
{"required_field":"CommonWord"}
{"index":{"_id":"8"}}
{"required_field":"CommonWord"}
{"index":{"_id":"9"}}
{"required_field":"CommonWord","optional_field":"RareWord AnotherRareWord"}
{"index":{"_id":"10"}}
{"required_field":"CommonWord","optional_field":"RareWord AnotherRareWord"}
```

**Search Query:**

If I run a search query similar to one below:

```
GET /my-index/_search
{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"RareWord AnotherRareWord","fields":["required_field","optional_field"]}}}
```

**Expectation**

The end-user would expect Document #9 and #10 to score higher than others, because they contain the exact two words of the search query in their **optional_field**

**Reality**

Document #1 would score better than #10, even though it only contains one of the the two words of the search query; which is the opposite of what end-users most likely expect.

**A closer look at _explain**

Here is the **_explain** results of running the same search query for Document #1:

```
{
  "_index" : "my-index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "matched" : true,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 1.4816045,
    "description" : "max of:",
    "details" : [
      {
        "value" : 1.4816045,
        "description" : "sum of:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 1.4816045,
            "description" : "weight(required_field:rareword in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 1.4816045,
                "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 2.2,
                    "description" : "boost",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 1.4816046,
                    "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                    "details" : [
                      {
                        "value" : 2,
                        "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 10,
                        "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 0.45454544,
                    "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                    "details" : [
                      {
                        "value" : 1.0,
                        "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 1.2,
                        "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 0.75,
                        "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 1.0,
                        "description" : "dl, length of field",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 1.0,
                        "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is the **_explain** results of running the same search query for Document #10:

```
{
  "_index" : "my-index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "10",
  "matched" : true,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.36464313,
    "description" : "max of:",
    "details" : [
      {
        "value" : 0.36464313,
        "description" : "sum of:",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 0.18232156,
            "description" : "weight(optional_field:rareword in 9) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 0.18232156,
                "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 2.2,
                    "description" : "boost",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 0.18232156,
                    "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                    "details" : [
                      {
                        "value" : 2,
                        "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 2,
                        "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 0.45454544,
                    "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                    "details" : [
                      {
                        "value" : 1.0,
                        "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 1.2,
                        "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 0.75,
                        "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 2.0,
                        "description" : "dl, length of field",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 2.0,
                        "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "value" : 0.18232156,
            "description" : "weight(optional_field:anotherrareword in 9) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 0.18232156,
                "description" : "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 2.2,
                    "description" : "boost",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 0.18232156,
                    "description" : "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                    "details" : [
                      {
                        "value" : 2,
                        "description" : "n, number of documents containing term",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 2,
                        "description" : "N, total number of documents with field",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 0.45454544,
                    "description" : "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                    "details" : [
                      {
                        "value" : 1.0,
                        "description" : "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 1.2,
                        "description" : "k1, term saturation parameter",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 0.75,
                        "description" : "b, length normalization parameter",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 2.0,
                        "description" : "dl, length of field",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      },
                      {
                        "value" : 2.0,
                        "description" : "avgdl, average length of field",
                        "details" : [ ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, Document #10 scores worse, mainly due to the lower IDF value (0.18232156). Looking closely, it's because IDF uses **N, total number of documents with field: 2**  instead of simply considering the total number of the documents in the index: 10.

**Question**

My question is that is there any way that I could force **multi_match** query to consider all the documents (instead of only those that contain the field) when computing the IDF value for an optional field, hence resulting in a relevance score which is closer to the expectations of the end-users?
Or alternatively, is there a better way to write the search query, so I get the expected results?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation seems to be similar to the one described in the [cross_fields query type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields) so you should probably try it:

```
{
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "RareWord AnotherRareWord",
    "fields": ["required_field","optional_field"], 
    "type": "cross_fields", 
    "operator": "and"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. cross_fields behaves the same way; the reason document #1 does not show up in search results if you run the query above is because of the "and" operator. If we change the operator to "or", the issue that I'm having persists. 
Your suggestion actually reminded me to try combined_fields query, which does not have the same issue, but still suffers from other limitations that are not ideal in my use-case (e.g., all fields need to use the same analyzer,  and I'm not sure how to use that for matching phrases)

Comment: Yeah makes sense. Another approach would be to use some third field in the mapping to gather all the data during indexing: `PUT /my-index {"mappings": { "properties": { "required_field": {"type": "text", "copy_to": "all_fields"}, "optional_field": {"type": "text", "copy_to": "all_fields"}}}}`

and then use it for search `GET /my-index/_search { "query": { "match": { "all_fields": "RareWord AnotherRareWord"}}}`

Comment: Using copy_to is a good idea, and should work in most cases where the queries don't change very often. Unfortunately in my case, depending on what search filters the user selects, the list of the fields that need to be included in the search query changes. So I can't copy them all to a field, because I don't know in advance which fields need to be included in search, if that makes sense. Btw, I really appreciate you replying back and suggesting solutions.